# Cannot redefine property of third-party module

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to modify part of the third-party implementation, but I got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property".

How can I resolve this problem?

btw, I am using babel and webpack to compile my code.

```js
import * as myLib from 'mylib';
    
Object.defineProperty(myLib, 'biHottag', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  set(value) {
    myLib.biHottag = value;
  },
  get() {
    return myLib.biHottag;
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: Here is your answer [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_redefine_property): `The JavaScript exception "can't redefine non-configurable property" occurs when it was attempted to redefine a property, BUT THAT PROPERTY IS NON-CONFIGURABLE.` (emphasis mine). In general, modifying third party modules in this was isn't a good idea anyway because it ends up being unclear who modified what/how it got modified. Could you expose a wrapper library/function and have your code use that wrapper? More code/explanation is needed to help further.

Comment: Yes I agree. 
But is there any way to make third-party module property configurable if it is non-configurable by default?

Comment: No, hence the error, but what are you actually trying to do? There's likely another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I just don't want to change the import statement :D. But ur right, I will implement wrapper now.